# printwindow witn EnumDesktopWindows returns black image

Tags: c++, windows

Below is my code:

```
int main()
{

    HDESK desktop;

    desktop = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());

    EnumDesktopWindows(desktop, EnumWindowsProc, 0);

    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    RECT rc;
    char buff[1024];

    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);

    HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(hwnd);

    HDC hdcCompatible = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);

    HBITMAP hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);

    SelectObject(hdcCompatible, hbmScreen);

    PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcCompatible, NULL);

    wsprintfA(buff, "T:\\%dx%d - %dx%d.bmp", rc.left, rc.right, rc.top, rc.bottom);

    CreateBMPFile(buff, hbmScreen, hdcCompatible);

    return true;

}
```

Everything works fine. However it also saves trash images with black inside. How can I resolve this? I have only 1 window opened. It saves it to `bmp`. But many trash images with black inside.

Comment: You have way more than one window. Some of them aren't visible and others are things you might not expect to be windows. You should look at what you're actually getting.

Comment: yes some not really window. but how i can detect this?

Comment: You must filder windows with styles (like WS_VISIBLE (IsWindowVisible)) but your code won't work for UWP apps (DWM)

Comment: yes. WS_VISIBLE helps. but now have some black images but below

Comment: all good now. am add new parameters like WS_VISIBLE. but how i can detect what window upper than previous